# ¿Como limpiar un campo concreto en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy con un formulario con diversos campos (nombre, apellidos, etc.)

Como podría hacer en JavaScript de el campo que tenga el foco al pulsar un botón de "Limpiar". Ya aparte, tengo el botón RESET que los limpia todos los campos.

Este seria mi HTML por ejemplo:

```
<form>
    <label>Nombre:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" value="" placeholder="Nombre"/><br>
    <label>Primer Apellido:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="apellido1" value="" placeholder="Primer Apellido"/><br>
    <label>Segundo Apellido:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="apellido2" value="" placeholder="Segundo Apellido"/><br>
    <label>Contraseña</label><br>
    <input type="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" /><br>
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reiniciar">
    <input type="button" id="limpiar" value="Limpiar Campo">
    <input type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Y esta es el JS:

```
window.onload = inicio;

function inicio(){
    document.getElementById("limpiar").addEventListener('click',limpiar);
}

function limpiar(){
    var activo = document.activeElement.id;
    activo.innerHTML = "";
}
```

El asunto es que quiero limpiar el campo de texto que tenga el foco, pero claro, ese campo lo pierde inmediatamente en el momento que se hace click en limpiar.

Espero que ahora esté más claro lo que ando buscando. Gracias.

Comment: Añade aunque sea el código de tu formulario

Comment: ¿Que quieres saber exactamente? ¿Que elemento es que tiene el foco para que cuando pulsas `limpiar` borre solo ese?

Comment: Pon código , lo que has intentado , etc ... No se hacen deberes. Eso yo por lo menos.

Comment: Espero que ahora este más completo. No necesito que me hagan los deberes, solo quiero ver donde estoy perdido.

Comment: Tú mismo te has respondido @acensito. Si pulsas en un botón, el foco lo gana el botón, por lo que lo que intentas es imposible a mi parecer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
// Creamos variable que almacenara el ID a borrar
var inputfocused = "";

// Le añadimos función de borrar al botón
document.getElementById("clearbutton").onclick = limpiaCampo;

// En este caso concreto seleccionamos todos los input text y password
// para una selección más precisa se puede usa una clase
// para una selección más general, se puede usar solo 'input'
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text'],input[type='password']");
// Por cada input field le añadimos una funcion 'onFocus'
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener("focus", function() {
    // Guardamos la ID del elemento al que hacemos 'focus'
    inputfocused = this;
  });
}

function limpiaCampo() {
  //Utilizamos el elemento al que hacemos focus para borrar el campo.
  inputfocused.value = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="campo 1" value="asdads" />
<input type="text" placeholder="campo 2" value="asd234234ads" />
<input type="text" placeholder="campo 3" value="asdwrwerfads" />
<input type="password" placeholder="campo 4" value="asdadfdgdds" />

<button id="clearbutton"> Limpiar Focus</button>
```

Comment: Totalmente correcto. He propuesto una edición con una solución menos restrictiva, dejando de ser dependiente de los ids de los inputs.

Comment: @CésarGonzález Perdón, creo que estábamos editando al mismo tiempo y he podido "pisar" tu edición. ¿Podrías hacerla de nuevo?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ya la ha dejado MK.O editada con mi propuesta.

Comment: He agregado la solución menos restrictiva de CésarGonzález  
@AlvaroMontoro Gracias por lo de hacer ejecutable el código.

He agregado los tipos de input que el autor de la pregunta está utilizando

Comment: El sistema de MK. O funciona estupendamente, parece enrevesado pero es sencillo. Gracias por las respuestas.

Comment: como haría si por ejemplo registro datos de un formulario, sin la necesidad de actualizar la pagina, pero quiero limpiar los campos que tenia la información.
(estoy aprendiendo a trabajar con AJAX)

Answer (score 4):

Para limpiar un campo de texto específico podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

Teniendo en tu HTML esto:

```
<input type="text" id="prueba"/>
<button onclick="limpiar()">Limpiar</button>
```

Puedes hacerlo con Javascript así:

```
function limpiar() {
    document.getElementById("prueba").value = "";
}
```

Dejo un ejemplo funcional en **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkdkrwyn/)**

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar esto:

```js
var ultimo = null;

function marcar(elemento) {
  ultimo = elemento;
}

function limpiar() {
  if (ultimo != null) {
   ultimo.value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="marcar(this);">
<br>
<input type="text" onfocus="marcar(this);">
<button onclick="limpiar()">Limpiar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mí me funciona esta manera que me parece muy sencilla: una vez creadas las variables con los valores de cada una, creas una función que muestre el valor de las variables vacías. A la función *limpiar* la asignás a un botón en HTML. De esa manera puedes seleccionar el campo que contenga la variable que tú específicamente quieres borrar.

---

```
var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value);
var op = document.getElementById("op").value;
var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value);
```

---

```
function limpiar() {

    n1.value = "";
    n2.value = "";
    op.value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías resetear el input con un eventListener y tendrías tu código más compacto y con el mismo funcionamiento.

```html
    <input type="text" id="input-Id" />
    <button id="btn-Delete">Borrar</button>
    
    
     <script>
        const btnDelete = document.getElementById("btn-Delete");
        const inputId = document.getElementById("input-Id");

        btnDelete.addEventListener("click", function () {
          inputId.value = "";
        });
    </script>
```